# Find and replace a string in Perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I have the following command line:

```
perl -i -pe 's/_GSV*//g' file.fasta
```

My goal is change some sequences that have the following pattern:

> GSVIVG01006342001_GSVIVT01006342001

I want to find all sequences that starts with _GSV and finish with anything (that`s why I put the '*') and substitute for nothing.

When I run my command it just recognize the _GSV and return to me that:

> GSVIVG01006342001IVT01006342001

and I want that:

> GSVIVG01006342001

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before the *, include a dot that means any character

```
perl -i -pe 's/_GSV.*//g' file.fasta
```

You can also include the symbol $ to ensure you arrive until the end of the string

```
perl -i -pe 's/_GSV.*$//g' file.fasta
```